# Create a repeating event with reminder until specific day without Intent in Android?

Tags: android, calendar, reminders, rrule

I have an android app that downloads with a service some drugs info.

For example (fludex white round 2 24-02-2012),means a drug named fludex ,white and round,must be given 2 times per day from today untill 24-01-2012.

Now i want after drug info downloading , to add repeated event with drug info to the calendar silently/programmatically(without user interaction).
So that from today untill 24-01-2012 every 10 am and 10pm to have a reminder 10 minutes before to take his drug.
My app will be for android 2-4.
How can i do that,i'm confused from my searching so far.

Second question:How can i delete only the events(and their reminders) made from my application,so when i sync my drug therapy to delete all previous events and produce new events based on the new drug therapy i receive from my service?

Comment: have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871921/add-weekly-event-to-calendar

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
        ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, dtstart);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, comment);
        
        TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

        // default calendar
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);

        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL="
                + dtUntill);
        // for one hour
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "+P1H");

        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);

        // insert event to calendar
        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

where dtuntil is

```
    SimpleDateFormat yyyymmdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmdd");
    Calendar dt = Calendar.getInstance();

    // where untilDate is a date instance of your choice,for example 30/01/2012
    dt.setTime(untilDate);

    // if you want the event until 30/01/2012 we add one day from our day
    // because UNTIL in RRule sets events Before the last day want for event
    dt.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
    String dtUntill = yyyymmdd.format(dt.getTime());

    // Uri
    Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

    // get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
    long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());

    // add 10 minute reminder for the event
    ContentValues reminders = new ContentValues();
    reminders.put(Reminders.EVENT_ID, eventID);
    reminders.put(Reminders.METHOD, Reminders.METHOD_ALERT);
    reminders.put(Reminders.MINUTES, 10);

    Uri uri = cr.insert(Reminders.CONTENT_URI, reminders);
```

Ref: [`Recurrence Rule`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3)

Comment: ctx is a Context variable.

Comment: @oikonomopo I get a 09-23 00:00:12.632: E/AndroidRuntime(813): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: expected 1 row from this query but query returned no data. check the query: SELECT canPartiallyUpdate FROM view_events WHERE _id = ?
 error

Comment: This is perfectly working fine on my HTC device 4.0.2 but same code not working in samsung device 4.4.2 .. Event rrule is :-

values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE,"FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=16;BYDAY=TU);

This event show only for few weeks. Any guess why?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good [Example](http://androidgenuine.com/?tag=setting-a-reminderalarm-on-android) of what you want.

**Update**
for more information about calender and implementing reminders or other stuff [see this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)

You can also get help from the following code

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", date);
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY"); //To set the repeat rule
intent.putExtra("endTime", date);
intent.putExtra("title", summary);
```

Comment: This creates/set a reminder/alarm on a certain date.But i want to make this repeat for N days from now.And i also i want insert events to the calendar,so that the user can see them in.

Comment: can we put duration using putExtra i.e. intent.putExtra("duration", custom time);

Answer (score 2):

To create a time bound reoccuring event over multiple days, we need to use [CalendarContract.Events.RRULE](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract.Events). 
The rule is combination frequency, count etc.

Lets say we need to create an event occuring daily for 10 days in a specific time period of day:

```
Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
            .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
                    beginCalendarTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
                    endCalendarTime.getTimeInMillis())
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, heading)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "To be added")
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION, location)
            .putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=10");
```