# How to add calendar events to default calendar, silently without Intent, in android 4?

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

I want to add calendar events programmatically (directly) in android 4+.  Is it this possible to be tested on emulator?  I don't own an android phone.  Some sample code would be appreciated.  I read Calendar Provider of android developers but I'm confused.  How can I add events to the default calendar of a user? I don't need to be synced.

EDIT: I do not want to launch an event adding Intent. Instead I want to add them completely from code and not launch another activity. I need to be able to test on an emulator that the events will be added to the main calendar of the default user of the device. How do I set up an emulator to view the default calendar of the user?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add calendar events in Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3721963/how-to-add-calendar-events-in-android)

Comment: @jww He wants to do it silently, differently from that other question

Comment: don't forget about this line <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13652168/how-to-add-calendar-event-with-reminder-repeated-every-day-until-specific-day) is a working example of what i eventually made it:

```
ContentResolver cr = ctx.getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, dtstart);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, comment);

TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, timeZone.getID());

// Default calendar
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);

values.put(CalendarContract.Events.RRULE, "FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL="
        + dtUntill);
// Set Period for 1 Hour
values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DURATION, "+P1H");

values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, 1);

// Insert event to calendar
Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);
```

where `dtuntil` is

```
SimpleDateFormat yyyyMMdd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
Calendar dt = Calendar.getInstance();

// Where untilDate is a date instance of your choice, for example 30/01/2012
dt.setTime(untilDate);

// If you want the event until 30/01/2012, you must add one day from our day because UNTIL in RRule sets events before the last day
dt.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
String dtUntill = yyyyMMdd.format(dt.getTime());
```

Ref: [`Recurrence Rule`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.8.5.3)

Comment: Shouldn't the format be "yyyyMMdd" instead of "yyyymmdd"? "m" means minutes according to this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: The alarm works for me only in this format: `values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM, false);`

Comment: have a look at this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28871921/add-weekly-event-to-calendar

Comment: why it does add events 3o days before in every date till the date  is select?

Comment: I want to catch the reminder event and want to call WebService for that reminder. How to achieve that with above code ?

Comment: cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values); crashes with nothing in logcat. PS: I've added & granted the permissions as per Marshmallow.

Comment: CALENDAR_ID = 1 must be 2 for event, or 3 for birthday event...
thanks

Comment: After running this code, will i be able to see an event in Google Calendar App ??

Answer (score 23):

I believe the section you are looking for is [Using an intent to insert an event](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert). In this section it describes how to create an intent for the event you want to add and then the default calender program on the emulator will respond and add it. You may have to set up a dummy profile so that the calendar program will start if you actually want to see that it receives the correct information.

---

**Code from [Android Dev Site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert):**

```
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 7, 30);
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 0, 19, 8, 30);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
    .setData(Events.CONTENT_URI)
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, beginTime.getTimeInMillis())
    .putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime.getTimeInMillis())
    .putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Yoga")
    .putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Group class")
    .putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The gym")
    .putExtra(Events.AVAILABILITY, Events.AVAILABILITY_BUSY)
    .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "rowan@example.com,trevor@example.com");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: No i want to  add this events programmatically.with like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7859005/how-to-read-and-edit-android-calendar-events-using-the-new-android-4-0-ice-cream

Comment: In that link they also show this method above. How is what I described not programmatic? You mean you do not want to use intents? You want to silently add events per say?

Comment: Yes i want  to silently add events to default calendar.

Answer (score 6):

**Dont Forget to add Permission to Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALENDAR"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR"/>
```

**Code from :->[Android Dev Site](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider#add-event)**

```
long calID = 3; // Make sure to which calender you want to add event 
long startMillis = 0;
long endMillis = 0;
Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
beginTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 7, 30);
startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 9, 14, 8, 45);
endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();


ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
values.put(Events.TITLE, "Hackathon");
values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION, "do some code");
values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
Uri uri = cr.insert(Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

// get the event ID that is the last element in the Uri
long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
```

Comment: what does calendar ID mean here ??

Comment: @PradeepkumarReddy i declared it already calID above. calID is calender id, in which calender provider you want to insert event. and as per documentation you should add calender id.

Comment: After running this code, will i be able to see an event in Google Calendar App ??

Comment: Have you tried Google Calendar API to create events ?? The GSuite documentation says that it is highly recommended to call this API from server environment rather than from mobile environment.

Comment: yes i tried with google calender and it worked fine with this code

Answer (score 3):

Using this code, you can programmatically add an event to device calendar. I have tested in Marshmallow, and it works fine for me.

```
private void addToDeviceCalendar(String startDate,String endDate, String title,String description, String location) {

        String stDate = startDate;
        String enDate = endDate;

        GregorianCalendar calDate = new GregorianCalendar();
        //GregorianCalendar calEndDate = new GregorianCalendar();

        SimpleDateFormat originalFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm");
        SimpleDateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy,MM,dd,HH,mm");
        Date date,edate;
        try {
            date = originalFormat.parse(startDate);
            stDate=targetFormat.format(date);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {}

        long startMillis = 0;
        long endMillis = 0;
        String dates[] = stDate.split(",");

        SD_YeaR = dates[0];
        SD_MontH = dates[1];
        SD_DaY = dates[2];
        SD_HouR = dates[3];
        SD_MinutE = dates[4];


        /*Log.e("YeaR ", SD_YeaR);
        Log.e("MontH ",SD_MontH );
        Log.e("DaY ", SD_DaY);
        Log.e(" HouR", SD_HouR);
        Log.e("MinutE ", SD_MinutE);*/

        calDate.set(Integer.parseInt(SD_YeaR), Integer.parseInt(SD_MontH)-1, Integer.parseInt(SD_DaY), Integer.parseInt(SD_HouR), Integer.parseInt(SD_MinutE));
        startMillis = calDate.getTimeInMillis();
/*
        try {
            edate = originalFormat.parse(endDate);
            enDate=targetFormat.format(edate);

        } catch (ParseException ex) {}


        String end_dates[] = endDate.split(",");

        String ED_YeaR = end_dates[0];
        String ED_MontH = end_dates[1];
        String ED_DaY = end_dates[2];

        String ED_HouR = end_dates[3];
        String ED_MinutE = end_dates[4];


        calEndDate.set(Integer.parseInt(ED_YeaR), Integer.parseInt(ED_MontH)-1, Integer.parseInt(ED_DaY), Integer.parseInt(ED_HouR), Integer.parseInt(ED_MinutE));
        endMillis = calEndDate.getTimeInMillis();*/

        try {
            ContentResolver cr = getActivity().getContentResolver();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, calDate.getTimeInMillis() + 60 * 60 * 1000);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, description);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_LOCATION,location);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.HAS_ALARM,1);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, 1);
            values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, Calendar.getInstance()
                    .getTimeZone().getID());
            System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone().getID());
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                return;
            }
            Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

            long eventId = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
            Log.d("Ketan_Event_Id", String.valueOf(eventId));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Ketan Ramani : Not working on Marshmellow device, no error though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to ask user to which calendar the event has to be added. As my requirement was this and didn't find the solution at one place. I have summarized and came up with this solution, hope it helps someone :)

```
final ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor ;
        if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
            cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "calendar_displayName" }, null, null, null);
        else
            cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "displayname" }, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst() ) {
            final String[] calNames = new String[cursor.getCount()];
            final int[] calIds = new int[cursor.getCount()];
            for (int i = 0; i < calNames.length; i++) {
                calIds[i] = cursor.getInt(0);
                calNames[i] = cursor.getString(1);
                cursor.moveToNext();
            }

            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
            final long startDate = sdf.parse(slotData.getSlot_date() + " " + slotData.getSlot_from()).getTime();
            final long endDate = sdf.parse(slotData.getSlot_date() + " " + slotData.getSlot_to()).getTime();

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Select any one");
            builder.setSingleChoiceItems(calNames, -1, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put("calendar_id", calIds[which]);
                    cv.put("title", title);
                    cv.put("dtstart", startDate);
                    cv.put("hasAlarm", 1);
                    cv.put("dtend", endDate);
                    cv.put("eventTimezone", TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

                    Uri newEvent ;
                    if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
                        newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/events"), cv);
                    else
                        newEvent = cr.insert(Uri.parse("content://calendar/events"), cv);

                    if (newEvent != null) {
                        long id = Long.parseLong( newEvent.getLastPathSegment() );
                        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                        values.put( "event_id", id );
                        values.put( "method", 1 );
                        values.put( "minutes", 15 ); // 15 minutes
                        if (Integer.parseInt(Build.VERSION.SDK) >= 8 )
                            cr.insert( Uri.parse( "content://com.android.calendar/reminders" ), values );
                        else
                            cr.insert( Uri.parse( "content://calendar/reminders" ), values );

                    }
                    dialog.cancel();
                }

            });

            builder.create().show();
        }
        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

After reading several posts and after a few tries.
I finally found this method to work well on Android 8 and 10.

My code:

```
    public void addEventToCalendar() {
    Context myContext = getContext();
    String[] projection = {"_id", "calendar_displayName"};
    Cursor calCursor = myContext.getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, projection, CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE + " = 1 AND "  + CalendarContract.Calendars.IS_PRIMARY + "=1", null, CalendarContract.Calendars._ID + " ASC");
    if(calCursor.getCount() <= 0){
        calCursor = myContext.getContentResolver().query(CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI, projection, CalendarContract.Calendars.VISIBLE + " = 1", null, CalendarContract.Calendars._ID + " ASC");
    }

    while (calCursor.moveToNext()) {
        long id = calCursor.getLong(calCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarContract.Calendars._ID));
        long startMillis;
        long endMillis;
        Calendar beginTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        beginTime.set(2021, 9, 22, 15, 30);
        startMillis = beginTime.getTimeInMillis();
        Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTime.set(2021, 9, 22, 16, 45);
        endMillis = endTime.getTimeInMillis();

        ContentResolver cr = Objects.requireNonNull(getActivity()).getContentResolver();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, startMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, endMillis);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "My event");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.DESCRIPTION, "Nice description");
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID, id);
        Log.i("ID","my Id"+ id);
        values.put(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());
        Uri uri = cr.insert(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, values);

        long eventID = Long.parseLong(uri.getLastPathSegment());
    }

}
```

I was able to test on different phones and the insertion is done on the google calendar as well as on a basic android calendar.

Normally this method makes sure to insert the event (s) in all the calendars available on the device. I couldn't test it but I have high hopes.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with above all answers but import is calender Id. you can not use 1 as samsung phone uses 1 for their calender(S Planner).So calender ID is id for which email you want event. you can get calender id by following code for specific event

```
int calenderId=-1;
        String calenderEmaillAddress="xxx@gmail.com";
        String[] projection = new String[]{
                CalendarContract.Calendars._ID,
                CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME};
        ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"), projection,
                CalendarContract.Calendars.ACCOUNT_NAME + "=? and (" +
                        CalendarContract.Calendars.NAME + "=? or " +
                        CalendarContract.Calendars.CALENDAR_DISPLAY_NAME + "=?)",
                new String[]{calenderEmaillAddress, calenderEmaillAddress,
                        calenderEmaillAddress}, null);

        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

            if (cursor.getString(1).equals(calenderEmaillAddress))
                 calenderId=cursor.getInt(0); //youre calender id to be insered in above 2 answer


        }
```