# How to Show toast when I switch Tab from BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, android-fragments, baseadapter

I want to Show a Tabbed based inside Dialog so for this I use [This Library.](https://github.com/ashishbhandari/AndroidTabbedDialog)

I am able to populate my Dialog and also Tab is switching from Tab_1 to Tab_2. But when I am clicking on its Cancel, Ok or Neutral Button, I am not getting Toast.

Please guide me how can I use Initialize `Fragments` and `Toast` on Button Click in my `BaseAdapter`.

My code is here

```
public class ContactListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements ISimpleDialogListener, ISimpleDialogCancelListener,IFragmentListener {
slidingListItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            contactListItems = contactList.get(position);
            String id_attende = contactListItems.getPhone();
            String id_attende_name = contactListItems.getName();


            TabDialogFragment.createBuilder(context, mFragmentManager)
                    .setTitle(id_attende_name)
                    .setSubTitle(id_attende)
                    .setTabButtonText(new CharSequence[]{"Calendar", "Summary"})
                    .setPositiveButtonText("Ok")
                    .setNegativeButtonText("Cancel")
                    .setNeutralButtonText("Neutral")
                    .setRequestCode(REQUEST_TABBED_DIALOG)
                    .show();
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
@Override
public void onCancelled(int requestCode) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case REQUEST_TABBED_DIALOG:
            Toast.makeText(context, "Dialog cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onNegativeButtonClicked(int requestCode) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TABBED_DIALOG) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Negative button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onNeutralButtonClicked(int requestCode) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TABBED_DIALOG) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Neutral button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onPositiveButtonClicked(int requestCode) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_TABBED_DIALOG) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Positive button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onFragmentViewCreated(Fragment fragment) {
    int selectedTabPosition = fragment.getArguments().getInt(PageFragment.ARG_DAY_INDEX, 0);
    View rootContainer = fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.root_container);
    Log.i(TAG, "Position: " + selectedTabPosition);

    switch (selectedTabPosition) {
        case 0:
            selectedTabPositionZeroCase(rootContainer);
            break;
        case 1:
            selectedTabPositionOneCase(rootContainer);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }


}

private void selectedTabPositionZeroCase(View rootContainer) {
    // add view in container for first tab
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View tabProductDetailLayout = li.inflate(R.layout.tab_one_layout, (ViewGroup) rootContainer);
    TextView textView = (TextView) tabProductDetailLayout.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView.setText("hello: tab1");
}

private void selectedTabPositionOneCase(View rootContainer) {
    // add view in container for second tab
    LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View tabProductDetailLayout2 = li.inflate(R.layout.tab_one_layout, (ViewGroup) rootContainer);

    TextView textView1 = (TextView) tabProductDetailLayout2.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
    textView1.setText("hello: tab2");
}

@Override
public void onFragmentAttached(Fragment fragment) {
    mMyScheduleFragments.add(fragment);
}

@Override
public void onFragmentDetached(Fragment fragment) {
    mMyScheduleFragments.remove(fragment);
}
}
```

Comment: where you are passing **callback** instance when creating a tab dialog?

Comment: and TabDialogFragment is your own class?

Comment: Hi rahul.. Thank you.. Actually i am calling callback using Interface . no error but Not displaying any toast or not showing tab_1 and tab_2 data when I am swiping inside dialog.

Comment: Please see the link which I had imported in my project and calling that projects callback

Comment: Hey, I have added my answer. Please go through it. If there is any problem, please let me know. I be there till your problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually from the link, you have provided, They are passing the **MainActivity.this** where you are passing **context** and there is a problem. So as per my suggestion just implement these callbacks in your **MainActivity.java** class instead of **Adapter** class.

Comment: Thank you Rahul . but still there is no any toast I am getting .. I applied in My Activity

Comment: Call backs are not doing anything. this is main problem. I already tried. but I really thank you for your friendly behavior.

Comment: Please update your question with latest code. Both activity and adapter classes.

Comment: Thank you  Rahul... I solved it.. Now working fine.. Thank you my hero :)

Comment: one more thing I would like to know Rahul. I am getting Date from Sqlite and want to set that date on Calender. Any Idea dear ?  Means I want to make Calendar eventfull.  Date which we are getting from SQLite I want to show Green else Red.. Can you help me?

Comment: is there any stackoverflow ticket so that i can look for your existing code too?

Comment: code will be so big so If you let me know any sample where You are fixing any Static date and Setting on Calendar. Any sample if you know then please share with me

Comment: I found **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709477/how-to-add-calendar-events-to-default-calendar-silently-without-intent-in-andr**. Please go through this.