# Is it possible to know if user opted to cancel calendar event insertion on Android?

Tags: android, calendar

I'm launching a calendar-insertion activity using the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
long endTime = startTime + 60 * 60 * 1000;

intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startTime);
intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endTime);
intent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Frank Zappa Live");
intent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "Madison Square Garden");

startActivity(intent);
```

So far so good. But how can I know if the user opted to cancel?

Comment: This code is kind of broken as is.  It assumes they use the default calendar app.  Many users don't.  You should never be assuming application names like that.The correct way to add to a calendar can be seen at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709477/how-to-add-calendar-events-to-default-calendar-silently-without-intent-in-andr  and it doesn't use an intent, so can't be canceled.

Comment: @GabeSechan: I don't want to insert an event silently. By design, I must leave the choice to the user to cancel.

Comment: Then you should pop up your own dialog to do that.  MANY users don't use, or even have installed, that calendar.  It won't work on about 50% of users.  The correct  way is via the link I showed you.  If you need a confirmation dialog, do that first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `startActivityForResult` and you will get `Activity#RESULT_OK` or `Activity#RESULT_CANCEL`
as a result.

From : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CalendarContract#ACTION_HANDLE_CUSTOM_EVENT